# Angular 4 Input Directive onSave

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I made a directive for a two-way binded input, on the event onKeyPress I give it the columbian format.
e.g. I input:

```
1000.25
```

And the directive change it to:

```
1.000,25
```

Now, before binding the value to my model I want to remove the given format, my questions are:

- Is there a way I can fire an event in the input directive when is being submitted (by a submit button)?
- And if it is possible, how?
  I really couldn't find anything alike, thanks in advance.

Comment: `on the event onKeyPress` what do you mean there? are you changing the model?

Comment: My bad, I'm using a HostListener in my directive to catch the **onKeyDown**, not onKeyPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access NgForm from you directive via DI. In that form you have ngSubmit observable. It emits values on form submit.

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

constructor(form: NgForm) {
  this.form.ngSubmit.subscribe(<do stuff>)
}
```

But are you sure you really need to physically modify model value? Probably you just need to modify VIEW value. Perhaps you need something like $formatters from AngularJS. You can research more reading [this article](https://blog.ngconsultant.io/custom-input-formatting-with-simple-directives-for-angular-2-ec792082976)

Comment: Actually I was following that article. But I wasn't sure of making the binding the way the writer did. But I'll give it a chance, thank you!